# Link with javascript:window.location

Tags: watir

Any idea how to click a link with the following criteria:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location='/app/exe/add.do?Id=8&val=1&callerURL=details';
```

I tried several variations to the following examples, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
#$ie.a(:href => "http://app.com/app/exe/add.do?Id=8&val=1&callerURL=details").click
#$ie.link(:xpath,"//a[contains(@href='/app/exe/add.do?Id=8&val=1&callerURL=details')]/").click
#$ie.link(:href => "javascript:window.location='/app/exe/add.do?Id=8&val=1&callerURL=details'").click
#$ie.execute_script(:href => "javascript:window.location='/app/exe/add.do?Id=8&val=1&callerURL=details'").click
$ie.link(:xpath,"//a[contains(@href='/app/exe/add.do?Id=8&val=1&callerURL=details')]/").fire_event('onclick')
```

Comment: Why don't you put the url in the `href` attribute of that link? :) are you trying to trick the user?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  For the first example, i tried $ie.link(:href =>....) etc.. with the href attribute.  There isn't any other properties to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to match the href by a string, it has to be an exact match. The variations you tried are missing some characters at the end.

Try:

```
$ie.link(:href => "javascript:window.location='/app/exe/add.do?Id=8&val=1&callerURL=details';").click
```

Note the `';` were missing before.

Though there must be something better to identify the link with. Perhaps its text or its parent elements. Going based on this href, which is probably dynamic given the `Id=8` part, is likely to be brittle.